# set the in-line style to image tag in the content query web part

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, content-query-web-part

I have to set the style to image tag with in-line instead of class.
                
Is it possible? How?

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask